# Generate a new .txt file every 24 hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to make a visitor counter with php that will create `yy-mm-dd.txt` everyday and contain the number of visitors that day and after 12 AM it will create a new `yy-mm-dd.txt` file.
As example today is 2019-06-02 so the text file will be `2019-06-02.txt` and in the next day, `2019-06-03.txt` file will be automatically created.

Here is what I tried but it is not creating new `2019-06-03.txt` file after 12 AM. It keeps the same `2019-06-02.txt` file

```
<?php

    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $fp = fopen('dates/'.$date.'.txt', "r");

       $count = fread($fp, 1024);

   fclose($fp);

       $count = $count + 1;

       $fp = fopen('dates/'.$date.'.txt', "w");

                 fwrite($fp, $count);

     fclose($fp);

 ?>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: So, what *does* happen?

Comment: @JohnConde It keeps the same `yy-mm-dd.txt` file

Comment: How you start your scrip with cron job or?

Comment: @stefo91 This script is executed everytime a visitor visits my webpage. No corn job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be working fine. We can also add `is_dir` and `file_exists` checks, and we can use either `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` or `file_get_content`/`file_put_content`, if we like. We can also add a `default_timezone` such as:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Then, our code would look like something similar to:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

$dir = 'dates';

if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}

$count = 1;
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$filename = $dir . '/' . $date . '.txt';

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $count);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    $count = (int) file_get_contents($filename) + 1;
    if ($count) {
        file_put_contents($filename, $count);
    } else {
        print("Something is not right!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `file_get_contents` then `file_put_contents`:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$content = file_get_contents(date('Y-m-d').'txt');
if($content !== FALSE){
   $count+=(int)$content;
}
file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d').'txt', $count);
?>
```